# Unknown index.html in Apache logs directory

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, logging, wordpress

My system:
CentOS 6.2 64bit
Apache 2.2.15
PHP 5.3.3
I have WordPress 3.3.1.

I have several domains on my server configured as virtual hosts.
The path to website files is the following: /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/

Logs file for this domain: /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/logs/

So, today I have found an unknown file "index.html" in logs directory. The website itself works fine and I can't see any changes to core files.

This index.html contains the following:

```
...
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=http://173.255.248.137"
...
```

This URL redirects to some wired chinese language courses on vimeo.com.
So, anyone has something similar or knows how does this file was uploaded to my server?
Any log files I have to check?

Thank you for help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check your website's directories (mostly theme directories, uploads directory, wp-admin subdirectories), and .htaccess files and the code of index.php, 404.php, wp-config.php. if there's something strange, you'll see. In my case, the first time had an cgi-ssh client in my twentyten theme directory, and the second time there was a eval(base64_decode()) code in every php pages.

Comment: could you find anything?

Comment: Hello tpaksu! Thanks for reply. Please read my answer above.

Comment: Didn't find anything. I don't have twentyten theme, my own themes seems fine. index.php wp-config.php are clear. I have searched for "base64_" and "eval" - still nothing suspicious. Actually website works fine.

Comment: well, they scan for every injectable script and try that.They have a brute force attacker with a lot of exploit definitions I guess.

Comment: I see, but I need to find out, how that file was uploaded to my server. :) This file was in logs directory with owner "root". So, whether it's apache vulnerability or as I have a VPS, it's an OpenVZ vulnerability. Or I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked WP, and can't see anything suspicious. I have break attempts like this from time to time:
WordPress Firewall has detected and blocked a potential attack!

Web Page:       www.mydomain.com//wp-content/plugins/1-flash-gallery/upload.php?action=uploadify&fileext=php

Warning: URL may contain dangerous content!

Offending IP:       178.137.167.112 [ Get IP location ]

Offending Parameter:    $_FILE = wp-xml.php

So, they are blocked by WP Firewall and I don't even have 1-flash-gallery plugin.

I think someone has tried to inject this "index.html" to my website, but it was saved to logs directory somehow. And I need to know how!